# Transition image in fragment of activity A to fragment of activity B in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I have been following these guides [[1](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/), [2](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)] to understand more about activity and fragment transitions and animations in Android.

My scenario seems to be different to all three examples given, in that I have an `<ImageView>` within a fragment of my `HomePageActivity` and OnClick of that ImageView within my `HomePageFragment` it loads up `DetailActivity` and the `DetailFragment` loads an `<ImageView>` at the top.

How can I provide a smooth transition animation of the first `<ImageView>` into the second?

I am using Xamarin for .NET, but I can follow Java logic if provided.

**HomePageFragment.cs** (I was trying a few different things)

```
var intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(DetailActivity));
intent.PutExtra("page", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page));
// .. test
SharedElementReturnTransition = TransitionInflater.From(this.Activity).InflateTransition(Resource.Transition.change_image_trans);
ExitTransition = TransitionInflater.From(this.Activity).InflateTransition(Resource.Transition.fade_trans);
// .. end test
//var options = ActivityOptionsCompat.MakeSceneTransitionAnimation(this.Activity, p1);
this.Activity.StartActivity(intent/*, options.ToBundle()*/);
```

**DetailActivity.cs**

```
var frag = new PageDetailFragment();
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    frag.SharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.From(this).InflateTransition(Resource.Transition.change_image_trans);
    frag.EnterTransition = TransitionInflater.From(this).InflateTransition(Resource.Transition.fade_trans);
}

frag.Arguments = Intent.Extras; // pass arguments across
SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, frag)
    .Commit();
```

excerpt **home_tile_item.axml** (repeated via RecyclerView)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTile"
        android:transitionName="topImageTransition"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

excerpt **page_detail_fragment.axml**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_image"
            android:transitionName="topImageTransition"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="400dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Also top_image's background is provided by Universal Image Loader, and in some cases *may* not load the same URL sent to imageTile. Additionally, is this ok?

Comment: Did you load images from web?

Comment: Have you found out a solution for this? Because I'm stuck at a similar point myself.

Comment: Nope. Sorry nothing yet.